# Dynamic og meta content asp.net webforms master and content page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages, meta-tags

I have a master page with head tag which uses some <%=%> tags for loading some contents like css, js and favicons.
I wish to dynamically construct **og** meta contents like

```
<meta property="og:title" .../>, 
<meta property="og:description" .../> 
<meta property="og:image" .../> etc
```

These data content will be generated from each content pages, and wish to put it on page head element

What I have tried so far is - in master page load event

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta tag = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta();
tag.Name = "og:title";
tag.Content = "blah";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
```

But it shows error that I have already used <%=%> block in my head tag.

Sample head element

```
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css?v=534521") %>">
</head>
```

Hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to fix the error: in the head, change `<%=` to `<%#`, and at the end of the code behind (Page_Load) add

```
Page.Header.DataBind();
```

Another possibility would be to wrap the link in a `Placeholder` control.